# Why is shell/terminal printing extra new line. What can be done to prevent it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, echo

```bsh
root@kali-linux:~# echo -ne "hi"
hi
root@kali-linux:~# echo "hi"
hi

root@kali-linux:~#
```

[image: shell]

I am using bash shell, xfce + i3wm + stterm in kali. On previous version of kali, there wasn't this feature/bug to add new line but from 2021.2 onwards it appeared I think. Also the problem isn't with echo but all other commands. Any way on how to revert the change?

Comment: What is the output of `declare -p PS1 PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: These two lines are the output of that command `declare -- PS1="\\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;31m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\\$ "`
`declare -- PROMPT_COMMAND="echo"` @glenn jackman

Comment: It's the [PROMPT_COMMAND variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND) that is causing the blank line.

Comment: How do i fix it?

Comment: look in your bash dot files (.bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile) to find where it's defined. Then either remove that definition, or change it. For immediate relief in your current shell: `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: oh so it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
unset  PROMPT_COMMAND
echo unset PROMPT_COMMAND | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc 
if [[ -f ~/.bash_profile ]]; then 
     echo unset PROMPT_COMMAND | tee -a ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

This should fix it permantly.